# How would you find the amount of 'usable power' in a typical coal mining process

Tags: mining-engineering

Suppose you have a typical coal mining process composed of the following steps:

(1) Excavation -> (2) Crushing -> (3) Storage -> (4) Rail -> (5) Power Station

The idea is the coal is excavated out of the ground, crushed and processed, stored, and finally transported by a diesel train to the power station. It is very simplistic and probably missing some steps, but it's just for ease of calculation purposes.

Now I'm interesting in finding the energy loss in each component of this process, scaled down to 1KW.

For example, if I start of with 1KW at the beginning of the process (step 1), how much usable power would be available for me at the end (step 5)?

Comment: So fuel consumption for all the machines used in the excavation process convert litres of fuel to an energy equivalent to match all the steps. Repeat for all steps. A common set of calculations often called grey energy. Usually set as a homework task for students in engineering, sustainability etc.

Comment: If this is your homework, you need to show more of your work and narrow down the question. But it loks like you want to know the Energy return on investment (EROI) of coal so how about googling that.